# On Visual Studio Code devcontainer rebuild: keep VSC plugins?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

For docker or docker-compose devcontainer projects. Every change of the Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml file Visual Studio Code wants to rebuild the containers. This also deletes all the installed VSC plugins. As it requests a rebuild even on addition of new environment variables and the like, this starts to be really frustrating and a time sink.

Hence, is there a way to install the plugins somehow/someplace where they survive a rebuild?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out by myself.

There is the `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json` file which contains following section:

```json
    // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
    "extensions": [
        "ms-python.python",
        "ms-python.vscode-pylance",
        "littlefoxteam.vscode-python-test-adapter"
    ],
```

The ID of an extension can be found on the introduction screen after installing it.